# Slow performance setting Excel sheet print settings

Tags: vb.net, excel, performance, office-interop

Using the Microsoft Office Interop libraries for Excel, I've written a routine in VB.Net that creates a large number of Excel worksheets, populates them and then formats them for printing.  For every worksheet I call this small method to set the print settings:

```
  Public Sub SetDefaultReportPrintSettings(orientation As ReportSheetOrientation, ws As Excel.Worksheet)

        CType(ws.Parent, Excel.Workbook).Application.Windows(1).Zoom = 90

        With ws.PageSetup
            Select Case orientation
                Case ReportSheetOrientation.Portrait : .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait
                Case ReportSheetOrientation.Landscape : .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
            End Select
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .LeftMargin = ws.Application.InchesToPoints(If(orientation = ReportSheetOrientation.Portrait, 0.75, 0.5))
            .RightMargin = ws.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
            .TopMargin = ws.Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = ws.Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .CenterHorizontally = True
        End With

    End Sub
```

When I benchmark, this sub alone is apparently taking about 0.98 seconds.  I don't understand why toggling a handful of settings would take that long. It might not seem like much, but when generating hundreds (or more) sheets this really adds to the routine time.  The Excel `application` instance is hidden, so I don't think this is a screen updating issue.

Any way to make this go faster?

Comment: i don't have any ways to make faster, but I do have a lot of experience working with page setup formatting in VBA and it always run slow. **Edit:** Actually, I have one thing that may help: `Top` and `Bottom` Margin is `.75` by default for `Portrait` or `Landscape`. So you can remove those lines.

Comment: I can second @ScottHoltzman's comment. I've written code that uses `PageSetup` extensively and it just runs slow. A lot faster than doing it by hand though! Especially the 23rd time :).

Comment: If you are interfacing to Excel 2010 or later, use `Application.PrintCommunication`.  Set it to False at top of your Sub, and True at the end

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I've never heard of that before. Great to know. Tekito, it would be great to hear the results of using this.

Comment: @ChrisNeilsen's suggestion helped. I'd give him the answer, but since a comment can't be an answer, I'll just type one up myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Neilen's comment (set `Application.PrintCommunication=False` during `PageSetup` modifications) significantly improved my run time.  According to documentation, Excel by default is actively communicating with the printer, which helps explain the slow performance.

I got an even bigger speed gain by setting Excel's view to `Normal` instead of `Page Break Preview`. This made a big difference, not in the `PageSetup` code, but for the rest of my Excel routines.  The documentation again explains Excel does additional calculations for page breaks.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835544.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/199505